# Error estimate of discretization of inproper integral

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, improper-integrals, contour-integration

In the [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/1593271.pdf) I found the following error estimation for the discretization error
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(u) du=:I \approx I_h:=h \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} g(kh),$$
for some complex valued function $g\in L^1(\mathbb R,\mathbb C)$.

---

**Theorem**: *Let $w=u+iv$, with $u$ and $v$ real. Suppose $g(w)$ is holomorphic in the strip $-d<v<c$ for some $c,d>0$ and $g(w)\to 0$ uniformly as $|w|\to \infty$ in that strip. Suppose further that for some $M_+,M_->0$ the function satisfies
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(u+ir)|du \leq M_+\qquad \text{and}\qquad \int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(u-is)|du,$$
for all $0<r<c$ and $0<s<d$. Then
$$|I-I_h|\leq DE_++DE_-$$
with
$$DE_+=\frac{M_+}{e^{2\pi c/h}-1}\qquad \text{and} \qquad DE_-=\frac{M_-}{e^{2\pi d/h}-1}.$$*

---

However, in the paper they do not give a proof for this statement, it was only written that it can be proven by using the residue theorem or some Fourier techniques. They referred to some paper/book which I could not find. So, I tried to prove it by my own and failed. If someone has an idea to fix my attempt or has some good links I would be greatfull. The following is my attempt to prove this statement.

---

Lets pick some $0<r<c$ and $0<s<d$.
At first lets use Chauchy's integral theorem and the uniform decay of $g$ to obtain
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(u)du = \int_{-\infty+iz}^{\infty +iz} g(u)du$$
for all $z\in (-d,c)$. Further, using the residue theorem we get
$$g(hk)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma_R-hk}\frac{g(u)}{u-hk} du,$$
for $\Gamma_R$ describes a rectangular closed curve given by the points $(-R,ir)$ and $(R,-is)$. Then by increasing $R\to \infty$ and the uniform decay of $g$ we get
$$g(hk)=\frac 1 {2\pi i} \left( \int_{-\infty +ir}^{\infty +ir} \frac{g(u)}{u-hk}du   +\int_{-\infty -is}^{\infty -is}\frac{g(u)}{u-hk}du\right).$$
It follows now
\begin{align*}|I-I_h|&= \left | \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(u)du-h \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} g(hk)    \right|\newline
&=\frac h {2 \pi}\left |  \frac{\pi i}{h} \int_{-\infty +ir}^{\infty+ir} g(u) du+ \frac{\pi i}{h} \int_{-\infty-is}^{\infty-is}g(u)du-\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}\int_{-\infty+ir}^{\infty+ir}\frac {g(u)}{u-hk} du+ \int_{-\infty-is}^{\infty-is} \frac{g(u)}{u-hk}du  \right |.
\end{align*}
Then I tried to find a proper series $\{a_k\}$ with $\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}a_k=1$ and continue with
\begin{align*}
|I-I_h| &=\frac h {2 \pi}\left | \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}\int_{-\infty+ir}^{\infty+ir}\left(\frac {a_k\pi i}h-\frac {1}{u-hk} \right)g(u) du+ \int_{-\infty-is}^{\infty-is} \left(\frac {a_k\pi i}h-\frac {1}{u-hk} \right)g(u)du  \right |\newline
^\text{triangle +Hölder}&=\frac h{2 \pi} \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}  \max_{u \in \mathbb R}\left | \frac{ia_k \pi}h- \frac 1 {u+ir-hk}\right| \cdot M_++\max_{u \in \mathbb R}\left | \frac{i a_k \pi }h- \frac 1 {u-is-hk}\right| \cdot M_-\newline
^\text{compute maxima}&=\frac h{2 \pi} \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} \left | \frac{ra_k \pi +h}{rh}\right| \cdot M_++\left | \frac{sa_k \pi -h}{sh}\right| \cdot M_-.
\end{align*}
I was hoping to find an appropriate sequence $a_k$ such that the sums on the right side become $\frac 1 {e^{2 \pi r/c}-1}$ and $\frac 1 {e^{2 \pi s/c}-1}$. But I failed. If we find one such sequence, we are done with the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** A correct computation for $g(kh)$ is:

$$ g(kh) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \left( \color{red}{\bbox[border:1px dotted red; padding:2px;]{-}} \int_{-\infty + ir}^{\infty + ir} \frac{g(z)}{z-hk} \, \mathrm{d}z + \int_{-\infty - is}^{\infty - is} \frac{g(z)}{z-hk} \, \mathrm{d}z \right). $$

**2.** Recall the well-known formula

$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{\substack{k \in \mathbb{Z} \\ |k| \leq N}} \frac{1}{z - hk} = \frac{\pi}{h} \cot \left(\frac{\pi z}{h} \right). $$

To make use of this formula, let $R_N = (N+\frac{1}{2})h$ and let $M \geq N$ be another integer. Then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{k \in \mathbb{Z} \\ |k| \leq N}} g(kh) h
&= \sum_{\substack{k \in \mathbb{Z} \\ |k| \leq M}} g(kh) h \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{|k| \leq N\}} \\
&= \sum_{\substack{k \in \mathbb{Z} \\ |k| \leq M}} \frac{h}{2\pi i} \oint_{\Gamma_{R_N}} \frac{g(z)}{z - hk} \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= \frac{h}{2\pi i} \oint_{\Gamma_{R_N}} g(z) \sum_{\substack{k \in \mathbb{Z} \\ |k| \leq M}} \frac{1}{z - hk} \, \mathrm{d}z.
\end{align*}

Letting $M \to \infty$ and invoking the cotangent limit above, which converges uniformly over the rectangle $\Gamma_{R_N}$, we get

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{k \in \mathbb{Z} \\ |k| \leq N}} g(kh) h
= \frac{1}{2i} \oint_{\Gamma_{R_N}} g(z) \cot\left(\frac{\pi z}{h}\right) \, \mathrm{d}z.
\end{align*}

Now letting $N \to \infty$ and noting that $\cot\left(\frac{\pi z}{h}\right)$ is uniformly bounded over $\bigcup_{N\geq 1} \Gamma_{R_N}$, we get

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{k \in \mathbb{Z} \\ |k| \leq N}} g(kh) h
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( i \int_{-\infty + ir}^{\infty + ir} g(z) \cot \left(\frac{\pi z}{h} \right) \, \mathrm{d}z - i \int_{-\infty - is}^{\infty - is} g(z) \cot \left(\frac{\pi z}{h} \right) \, \mathrm{d}z \right).
\end{align*}

Consequently, the difference between $I$ and $I_h$ is given by

\begin{align*}
I - I_h
&= \frac{1}{2} \biggl( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x+ir)\left[ 1 - i \cot \left(\frac{\pi(x+ir)}{h} \right) \right] \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\hspace{2.5em} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x-is)\left[ 1 + i \cot \left(\frac{\pi(x-is)}{h} \right) \right] \, \mathrm{d}x \biggr).
\end{align*}

**3.** Now a tedious computation shows that, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r, h > 0$,

$$ \left| 1 - i \cot \left(\frac{\pi(x+ir)}{h} \right) \right| = \sqrt{\frac{2 \exp(-2\pi r/h)}{\cosh(2\pi r/h) - \cos(2\pi x/h)}} \leq \frac{2}{e^{2\pi r/h} - 1}. $$

Taking complex conjugate to the expression inside the absolute value and replacing $r$ by $s$, we also obtain

$$ \left| 1 + i \cot \left(\frac{\pi(x-is)}{h} \right) \right| \leq \frac{2}{e^{2\pi s/h} - 1}. $$

Combining all these computations, we conclude the theorem.

Comment: In step 2, we pull the sum inside the integral. I have some trouble to find a justification that we are allowed to do that. Since, the given series is not absolute convergent, nor is that series monotonically increasing.

Comment: But I think we can use $g(hk)=\int_{\Gamma_R-hk} g(u)(\frac{1}{u-hk}+\frac{1}{hk}) du$ instead. This remains true, since the integral of $g$ over that closed curve is 0. Then we get later in step 2 $\frac 1 z\sum_{0\neq k\in \mathbb Z}\frac 1 {z-hk} +\frac 1 {hk}$=\frac \pi h \cot(\frac{\pi z} h), which converges absolutely. Hence we are allowed to pull the sum inside the integral.

Comment: Ok, I am pretty sure this attempt does not work either. So i would be very grateful for some justification, that we are allowed to pull the sum inside.

Comment: @Salfalur, Sorry for the late reply. And I see your point. Indeed it seems challenging, if not possible, to justify the interchange of the order of sum and integral in my original answer. Instead, we can first swap the order for $\int_{\Gamma_R}$ and then let $R\to\infty$. I edited my answer accordingly.